# Lambda expression, outer variables in multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

Lets take this code:

```
public void Hit(int npage)
        {
            bool fetch = false;
            lock (pagesHit)
            {
                if (!pagesHit.Contains(npage))
                {
                    pagesHit.Add(npage);
                    fetch = true;
                }
            }
            if (fetch)
            {
                pageFiller.Completed += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        lock (pagesHit)
                        {
                            pagesHit.Remove(npage);
                        }
                    };
            }

        }
```

this function can be called from different threads. The goal is obviously to avoid fetching a page that is already scheduled for fetch. The filler object exposes an event that is subscribed via a lambda expression. My question is: can we say that the parameter *npage* is correctly handled in multithread scenario ? better: each event subscription  receive its own *npage* parameter, or the last *npage* seen is propagate to all events ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable capture happens per the *declaration scope* of `npage`. The parameter `npage` is declared at the method level, and does not change within that method - so indeed, the use of `npage` is *entirely* thread-safe.

The problem you are avoiding would occur if you were *changing* a variable within its declared scope, typically a loop - i.e.

```
for(int npage = 0; npage < 100 ; npage++)
    Foo( (s,e) => DoSomething(npage) ); // not safe; npage shared between all
```

however, by breaking it into a method you avoid this, i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Hit(i);
...
void Hit(int npage) {
    Foo( (s,e) => DoSomething(npage) ); // safe; npage is per-call
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `Hit` method invoke will have different values for *npage* reference.

In other words, each thread invoking this method will have its own *npage*.

That's because, for every thread invoking this method, its operations and event handler subscription will take place in different scopes, so, *npage* reference will point to scope's value.